# Regular expression: combining statments with or operator

Tags: regex, boolean-logic

I need a regular expression which roughly combines the logic of

**?[1-9][0-9]*+\s*+X|x**

with

**X|x+\s*+[1-9][0-9]***

Or in english: match a pattern of the letter X (capitalised or uncapitalised) preceded by an integer (single space optional) **OR** succeeded by an integer (single space optional)

Thanks.

P.S. The two separate regex above are just for illustration; haven't actually tested them.

Comment: It's a lot easier for us to help you if you give us actual code, not just illustrative examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, you need enclosing brackets to group as a capture group and to handle numbers other than those 2 digits long.

```
/([0-9]+\s{0,1}(X|x))|((X|x)\s{0,1}[0-9]+)/g
```

Paste it into http://regexr.com/ to try it out. I tested it with:

```
X9847 
X 2645
4442 x
x 525521
5254X5541
221 X 266
```

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you want:

```
(\d\s?[xX]{1}|[xX]{1}\s?\d)
```

[image: Example]

See http://regexr.com/.

Might not be the [best regex](https://www.loggly.com/blog/regexes-the-bad-better-best/).

Comment: And you can remove the `{1}`s. :)

Answer (score 1):

You said `single space optional` so i used `\s?`. If you can have any amount of whitespace, replace `\s` with `\s*` Try using this:

```
\d+\s?(X|x)|\s?\d+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sQ5hQ2/1)

Answer (score 1):

This will work and matches specifically to your request: 
**`((X|x)\s*\d+)|(\d+\s*(X|x))`**

Explanation:

```
(
  (X|x) First character must be an 'X' or 'x'
   \s*  Second character can be zero or infinite amount of spaces 
   \d+  Third character has to be one or more digits
)
|  or
(
  \d+   First character has to be one or more digits
  \s*   Second character can be zero or infinite amount of spaces
  (X|x) Third character must be an 'X' or 'x'
)
```